# I can't find a way to compile phpenmod phpdismod phpquery from the source packages of php (7.2.9-1)

Tags: php, compilation

After long research, I can't find any way to compile from the source files of php (7.2.9-1) I preferred to compile php to get really specifics settings. If it's possible I would like to know how thanks for your time.

Comment: This sounds more like question for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a way to compile phpenmod, phpdismod, phpquery

These are shell scripts, they don't need no compilation.

Available in debian git repo here: https://salsa.debian.org/php-team/php-defaults

Comment: sorry I used bad words I meant are they present in the source files of PHP ?  and if they are present is it possible to configure the php compilation from it source files  to install them with php ? I have the feeling they are not but it's worth asking, Thanks you for the repo tho.

Comment: No, they are debian extensions, and are not available in official PHP sources (as they are specific to debian PHP configuration layout). You can get them from Debian git (the link is included in the answer).

Comment: That's what I understood while reading the content of the scripts in the Debian git repo you have provided, I could have search for a long time in the PHP sources, it does mean I will have to edit the scripts to make them compatible with my own PHP installation, I guess symlinking will continue to serve me. thanks for your time.